# Component communication in Angular fails from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to apply @Output in my sample project following [this](https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/learn/lecture/6656076#overview) tutorial. I am unable to get it working. There are no compilation errors or any specific error for this in console. I am unable to figure out how to proceed with debugging @Output using developer tools. Below are my files.

app-component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverElements = [{type: 'server', name: 'testServer', content: 'Just a Server'}];
  constructor(){
    console.log(this.serverElements);
  }
  
  onServerAdded(serverData: {serverName: string, serverContent: string}) {
    console.log("Server Added");
    this.serverElements.push({
      type: 'server',
      name: serverData.serverName,
      content: serverData.serverContent
    });
    console.log("Server Added");
  }

  onBlueprintAdded(blueprintData: {serverName: string, serverContent: string}) {
    this.serverElements.push({
      type: 'blueprint',
      name: blueprintData.serverName,
      content: blueprintData.serverContent
    });
  }



}
```

app-component.html

```
  <app-cockpit (serverAdded)="onServerAdded($event)"
  (blueprintAdded)="onBlueprintAdded($event)"></app-cockpit>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-server-element *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements" [element] = "serverElement"></app-server-element>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

cockpit-component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cockpit',
  templateUrl: './cockpit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cockpit.component.css']
})
export class CockpitComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() serverAdded = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string, serverContent: string}>();
  @Output() blueprintAdded = new EventEmitter<{blueprintName: string, blueprintContent: string}>();
  newServerName = '';
  newServerContent = '';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onAddServer() {
    console.log(this.newServerContent);
    console.log(this.newServerName);
    this.serverAdded.emit({
      serverName:this.newServerName, 
      serverContent:this.newServerContent
    });
  }

  onAddBlueprint() {
    this.blueprintAdded.emit({
      blueprintName:this.newServerName, 
      blueprintContent:this.newServerContent
    });
  }
}
```

cockpit-component.html

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>Add new Servers or blueprints!</p>
      <label>Server Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerName">
      <label>Server Content</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerContent">
      <br>
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="onAddServer()">Add Server</button>
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="onAddBlueprint()">Add Server Blueprint</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I can see the console prints in the browser for cockpit-component.ts file but this does not lead to a call to onServerAdded() method in app component.
[image]

It works now after starting angular and vscode again
[image]

Comment: I can't see a reason as to why this is not working. Can you create a project on StackBlitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yk7ssu?file=src/styles.css here it is. I dont know why it works on stackblitz...when i ran again in my local after restarting vscode it works there too.